# getting N number in a number

Tags: php

I have an array and I am getting its length using `sizeof()`. In the size of the array I want to get how many 10 there are in that number. I used `%` in getting my number like:

```
$arraysize = 13;//sizeof($array)
$numberoften = $arraysize % 10 // getting 3
```

From here I know that I am wrong. What i want to get is 2. Because I want to get every 10. Like if length is 9 I want to get 1. If length is 31 I want to get 4.

What is the correct function of way to get my desired output?

Comment: `ceil($arraySize / 10)` ~ http://php.net/manual/function.ceil.php

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you mean by *"how many 10 in my number"*? The `%` operator gets the remainder. How are there any `10`'s in`9`? It would make more sense if `9` gave `0` and `31` gave `3`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek 31 will give 4 because 30 will give and the extra 1 will be fourth. 9 will give only since it is under 10 when 11 it will be 2 because 10 plus extra 1. I hope it is clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/function.ceil.php)

> Returns the next highest integer **value** by rounding up value if necessary.

```
$numberoften = ceil($arraysize / 10);
```

---

There's also `floor()` if you want to round the number down to the nearest integer. This would seem to fit better with your question...

> *I want to get how many 10 there are in that number*

Comment: i think ceil is better fit because if value is 9 it is under 10 so 1 when value is 11 it is 2 because it is 10 plus extra 1 same until 19 then 20 will give 2 since it is exact 2 number of 10

Comment: @Martin the way you have worded your question is odd. If you ask *"how many 10's in 9?*", the answer is *"zero"*, not *"one"*

Comment: sorry my English is not very good it is my bad :) but it was the solution

Comment: @Martin that's ok. You gave a good example of what you wanted the answer to be

Answer (score 0):

Use ceil() function

```
 $arraysize = 13;//sizeof($array);
$numberoften =ceil( $arraysize/10);
```

Or

Use round() function

```
$arraysize = 13;//sizeof($array);
$numberoften =round( $arraysize/10);
```